# How to use Next Auth & OAuth to fetch from a Google API (e.g. Youtube's API)

Tags: next.js, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, next-auth

I'm using NextAuth's Google Provider for Google account sign-ins. I've successfully authenticated users and now I'd like to make API calls to YouTube's API for authenticated user details. I am not sure how to use the access_token or id_token from Google in my GET requests.

Here's an example of what my logs show in terms of the response I get back from Google when I sign in (personal details redacted for privacy):

```js
[next-auth][debug][OAUTH_CALLBACK_RESPONSE] {
  profile: {
    id: '[REDACTED]',
    name: '[REDACTED]',
    email: '[REDACTED]',
    image: '[REDACTED]'
  },
  account: {
    provider: 'google',
    type: 'oauth',
    providerAccountId: '[REDACTED]',
    access_token: '[REDACTED]',
    expires_at: [REDACTED],
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    id_token: '[REDACTED]',
  },
  OAuthProfile: {
    iss: 'https://accounts.google.com',
    azp: '[REDACTED]',
    aud: '[REDACTED]',
    sub: '[REDACTED]',
    email: '[REDACTED]',
    email_verified: true,
    at_hash: '[REDACTED]',
    name: '[REDACTED]',
    picture: '[REDACTED]',
    given_name: '[REDACTED]',
    locale: 'en',
    iat: [REDACTED],
    exp: [REDACTED]
  }
}
```

So, I can literally *see* the access_token in this log data, but I don't know how to use it client-side to make calls to Youtube's api.

For additional context, this is my current Next Auth config:

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const options = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt(token, user, account) {
            try {
                if (token.token.account?.access_token) {
                    token.accessToken = token.token.account.access_token;
                }
                return token;
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        },
        async session(session, token) {
            try {
                if (token) {
                    session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
                }
                return session;
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        },
    },
    debug: true,
};

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```

I have tried to use this implementation to add the `access_token` returned from Google to the NextAuth session data. I expected the session to have this information by default, but when I observed that it didn't I tried to adjust the callbacks in the Next Auth config shown above. I think I need this access token to fetch from YouTube's api as an authenticated user (per this [youtube api documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)), but I haven't found a solution for adding this information to the session.

Is there a way to add it? Am I even supposed to have the access_token available in the session data?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself! It was a syntax error. I wasn't properly destructuring the parameters in my NextAuth callbacks. Here is the working Next Auth config file:

`src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const options = {
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account }) {
            if (account) {
                token.accessToken = account.access_token;
            }
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user = token;
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
            return session;
        },
    },
};

export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);
```

Notice the added curly braces in the jwt and session callbacks.

Also, here's the [Next Auth documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) that explains why this manual addition of the `accessToken` needs to be done.

Hope this helps!